# How to split string with 2 arguments?

Tags: python, string, split

If I have a string thats `'asdf foo\nHi\nBar thing'`, I want it to split the string, so the output is `['asdf', 'foo', 'hi', 'bar', thing']`. Thats essentially `x.split(' ')` and `x.split('\n')`. How can I do this efficiently? I want it to be about one line long, instead of having a for loop to split again...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Omit the parameter to `split()`: `x.split()` will split on both, spaces and newline characters (and also tabs).

Example:

```
>>> x = 'asdf foo\nHi\nBar thing'
>>> x.split()
['asdf', 'foo', 'Hi', 'Bar', 'thing']
```

Comment: How do I make it so the output is [['asdf', 'foo'], ['hi'], ['bar', 'thing']]? So that \n makes makes a new list in the list, and the spaces separate that list :P

Comment: [s.split(" ") for s in x.split('\n')]